# Why is my controller action filter no longer invoked once I override SSL settings with a "location" element?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application with an action filter attribute applied to a controller:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(
        ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(
            "MyFilterAttribute", "entered" );
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(
        ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
         filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(
             "MyFilterAttribute", "exited" );
    }
}

[MyFilter]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

MVC routing maps `/MyPath/MyAction` to the controller-action pair above.

and the client code invokes `https://my.company.com/MyPath/MyAction` and dumps the response headers.

Initially it works - I see that the response received on the client contains two `MyFilterAttribute` headers as expected.

Then I add a `location` element to web.config:

```
<configuration>
  // lots of stuff, then
  <location path="MyPath">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert"/>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

and once I redeploy with these changes the response headers no longer contain the two `MyFilterAttribute` items.

Adding `location` to web.config is the only change. Once I remove it the old expected behavior is back.

It looks like adding a `location` elements somehow breaks MVC attributes.

What might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert"` requests that IIS opens a mutually verified channel which is not the default behavior. I looked into IIS logs and it's HTTP 403.16 (client certificate untrusted) all the time. Because the client certificate is self-signed IIS doesn't trust it and so fails to open a mutually verified channel.

Either I have to not use `SslNegotiateCert` (and then the client certificate is not passed to application code) or I need a certificate which IIS trusts ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40216572/57428) explains how that can be achieved).